# JAVA Recursive addition from input stream using Scanner

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write the definition of a method that receives a reference to a scanner object associated with a stream of input consisting on integers only.  The method should read all the integers remaining to be read from the stream and return their sum. So if the input were 3 51 204 17 1040, the return value should be 1315. This method should accomplished recursively without any loops.

Unfortunately I can not access the files that are being read but when I attempt to run the method I do not receive any error but my outputs are coming out wrong. From a file that has 1 2 3 I am getting 129 as an output instead of 6 and from a file with 3 51 204 17 1040 I am getting 1444 as an output not 1315.  Any advice to where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
static int sum = 0;

public static int add(Scanner sc){    
    if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int val = sc.nextInt();    
        sum += val;            
        add(sc);                                
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `sum` is a data member (the fact that it's `static` is inconsequential to the issue at hand), each call to `add` modifies **the same variable**, and you end up adding the same values multiple times. Instead, you should rewrite the function so it only uses local variables:

```
public static int add(Scanner sc) {    
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int val = sc.nextInt();    
        return val + add(sc);                                
    }
    return 0; // No more values in the Scanner to add
}
```

Comment: Thank you, My train of thought was that it wouldnt be able to accomplish the task like that because i thought the val variable would be redefined before any addition took place.